# Multi-threaded websocket server on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

Please help me to improve this code:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import threading
import socket



class WebSocketServer:
    def __init__(self, host, port, limit, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize websocket server.
        :param host: Host name as IP address or text definition.
        :param port: Port number, which server will listen.
        :param limit: Limit of connections in queue.
        :param kwargs: A dict of key/value pairs. It MAY contains:<br>
        <b>onconnect</b> - function, called after client connected.
        <b>handshake</b> - string, containing the handshake pattern.
        <b>magic</b> - string, containing "magic" key, required for "handshake".
        :type host: str
        :type port: int
        :type limit: int
        :type kwargs: dict
        """
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.limit = limit
        self.running = False
        self.clients = []
        self.args = kwargs


    def start(self):
        """
        Start websocket server.
        """
        self.root = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.root.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.root.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.root.listen(self.limit)
        self.running = True

        while self.running:
            client, address = self.root.accept()
            if not self.running: break

            self.handshake(client)
            self.clients.append((client, address))

            onconnect = self.args.get("onconnect")
            if callable(onconnect): onconnect(self, client, address)

            threading.Thread(target=self.loop, args=(client, address)).start()

        self.root.close()



    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop websocket server.
        """
        self.running = False



    def handshake(self, client):
        handshake = 'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\n\r\n'
        handshake = self.args.get('handshake', handshake)
        magic = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
        magic = self.args.get('magic', magic)

        header = str(client.recv(1000))
        try:
            res = header.index("Sec-WebSocket-Key")
        except ValueError:
            return False
        key = header[res + 19: res + 19 + 24]
        key += magic
        key = hashlib.sha1(key.encode())
        key = base64.b64encode(key.digest())

        client.send(bytes((handshake % str(key,'utf-8')), 'utf-8'))
        return True



    def loop(self, client, address):
        """
        :type client: socket
        """
        while True:
            message = ''
            m = client.recv(1)
            while m != '':
                message += m
                m = client.recv(1)

            fin, text = self.decodeFrame(message)

            if not fin:
                onmessage = self.args.get('onmessage')
                if callable(onmessage): onmessage(self, client, text)
            else:
                self.clients.remove((client, address))
                ondisconnect = self.args.get('ondisconnect')
                if callable(ondisconnect): ondisconnect(self, client, address)
                client.close()
                break




    def decodeFrame(self, data):
        if (len(data) == 0) or (data is None):
            return True, None
        fin = not(data[0] & 1)
        if fin:
            return fin, None

        masked = not(data[1] & 1)
        plen = data[1] - (128 if masked else 0)

        mask_start = 2
        if plen == 126:
            mask_start = 4
            plen = int.from_bytes(data[2:4], byteorder='sys.byteorder')
        elif plen == 127:
            mask_start = 10
            plen = int.from_bytes(data[2:10], byteorder='sys.byteorder')

        mask = data[mask_start:mask_start+4]
        data = data[mask_start+4:mask_start+4+plen]

        decoded = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(data):
            decoded.append(data[i] ^ mask[i%4])
            i+=1

        text = str(bytearray(decoded), "utf-8")
        return fin, text



    def sendto(self, client, data, **kwargs):
        """
        Send <b>data</b> to <b>client</b>. <b>data</b> can be of type <i>str</i>, <i>bytes</i>, <i>bytearray</i>, <i>int</i>.
        :param client: Client socket for data exchange.
        :param data: Data, which will be sent to the client via <i>socket</i>.
        :type client: socket
        :type data: str|bytes|bytearray|int|float
        """
        if type(data) == bytes or type(data) == bytearray:
            frame = data
        elif type(data) == str:
            frame = bytes(data, kwargs.get('encoding', 'utf-8'))
        elif type(data) == int or type(data) == float:
            frame = bytes(str(data), kwargs.get('encoding', 'utf-8'))
        else:
            return None

        framelen = len(frame)
        head = bytes([0x81])

        if framelen < 126:
            head += bytes(int.to_bytes(framelen, 1, 'big'))
        elif 126 <= framelen < 0x10000:
            head += bytes(126)
            head += bytes(int.to_bytes(framelen, 2, 'big'))
        else:
            head += bytes(127)
            head += bytes(int.to_bytes(framelen, 8, 'big'))
        client.send(head + frame)
```

It works fine. 
I want the server to use all the processor cores for improved performance. And this code is not effective in high quantities connections. How to implement a multi-threaded solution for this case?

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Probably a question for [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You need sub-processing, not threading.

Comment: can you send or write an example?

Comment: i think the algorithm is: create subprocesses in number of cores count => in each process execute the code of _start_ method. BUT I cant understand, how to send data between processes correctly.

Comment: Yes I can write an example but no, i will not. As you've already learned communication between different processes is not easy, quite frankly it is convoluted, but there are modules in python to help ease the pain with multiprocessing (http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Ah and as a side note, if you want to bring somones attention then remember to mention them with @ before their name (like @alex).

Comment: server works on the principle of the chat. each new message from one client should be sent to everyone else. suitable for data exchange JoinableQueue?

Comment: Possibly, i don't know. Go, try it, if you run into a problem feel free to open a new question about it.

Comment: brainstorming begins!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that
>   prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at
>   once.

So your code won't work. You can use [processeses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threads (not on Windows*), [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html) if you want to support more than one client at the same time.

If your choice is multiprocessing, try this:

client.py:

```
import socket

def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("localhost", 5555))

    while True:
        data = raw_input("> ")
        s.send(data)

        if data == "quit":
            break

    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

server.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid

import socket

def receive(conn):
    print "(%d) connected." % getpid()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data:
            if data == "quit":
                break
            else:
                print "(%s) data" % getpid()

def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(("localhost", 5555))
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        conn, address = s.accept()
        print "%s:%d connected." % address
        Process(target=receive, args=(conn,)).start()

    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*On Windows this code will throw an error when pickling the socket:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
```

Comment: Threads work fine in Python for I/O bound tasks - multiple threads can indeed run concurrently then (the GIL is released around most potentially blocking I/O calls).  And, as the docs you linked to say, `multiiprocessing` works fine on Windows too.

Comment: When I say "not on Windows" I'm talking about sockets. Try passing a socket object as an argument to a new process.

Comment: @cdonts, yes, I have come across a problem you described. It's imposible to send sockets between proccesses. I need some time to make it works. And when I finish, I will post working code here.

Guys, if you have some code examples, post them here, please.

Comment: Thank you for the clear example. however, in this case, the number of clients is the number of processes. sneaking suspicion that this is not the right approach. after a while I'll post my code.